# Are the Gödel's incompleteness theorems valid for both classical and intuitionistic logic?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, incompleteness

I am studying an undergraduate text about math logic.
The proofs of the two Gödel's incompleteness theorems are not completely formal: they are admittedly simpler that the real proofs.
For what I understood, I deduce the two theorems are valid for both classical and intuitionistic logic.

Is my deduction correct?

Comment: as i mentioned in similar question in phil.SE, this is correct only for **IL** formalised as an alternative classical logic (with modification of syntax rules) and then terated as a formal suntax system. **But this is not intuitionism**, the difference lies in semamtics (although this is overlooked in formal approaches to logic).

Comment: In fact Brewer foresaw the incompletenes theorems of Goedels  when accepted propositions which can neither be proved nor refuted in intiotionism (up to current knowledge), in tjis sense incompleteness theorems are already embeded in intuitionism from the start. One has to be aware of a classical /syntactic treatment of a logic (e.g intuitionistic) and the actual philosophy like intuitionism which has tio do with semantics

Comment: a nice post ["Gödel’s Proof and Intuitionism"](http://www.jamesrmeyer.com/ffgit/intuitionism.html) in the same direction and meaning as my previous comments ([similar question on  phil.SE](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7194/how-is-g%c3%b6dels-incompleteness-theorem-interpreted-in-intuitionistic-logic))

Comment: The comment by Nikos is utter nonsense. I've just looked at the webpage he linked to and it is pure rubbish. I'm speaking as a logician, but nobody should simply take my word for it; just go ahead and study logic and it will be clear that what I say is true.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The usual proof of Gödel's First Incompleteness Theorem is entirely constructive. We don't have to rely on excluded middle, or have to rely on proving an existential quantification for which we can't produce a witness. For recall: the proof consists in (a) giving a recipe which takes a suitable specification of a sufficiently strong theory $T$ and constructs a certain sentence $G_T$ and then (b) showing $G_T$ is undecidable in that theory. The construction of $G_T$ is clever though simple when you see how, and involves no infinitary ideas. The proof of undecidability involves a pair of reductios, but both of the non-contentious type [like  "Suppose $T \vdash G_T$: then contradiction; so $T \nvdash G_T$"]. So overall the proof is intuitionistically acceptable.

The usual proof of the Second Incompleteness Theorem then consists, at heart, in showing that the proof of the First Theorem can be coded up in arithmetic. Again it's all constructive, and so is intuitionistically acceptable.

Comment: Historically this is the strength of the incompleteness theorems. They are foundationally indisputable in this sense. They don't appeal to set theory, nor to LEM. Just the natural numbers.

Comment: Yes indeed: @AsafKaragila's observation is exactly right.

Comment: I know, I made a footnote to your answer which is really a footnote, rather than a full answer with the classical P. Smith preface "This answer is really just a footnote to ...'s answer" ;-)

Comment: *Do* "people sometimes say that infinities are the troublemakers" with respect to Gödelian incompleteness? Really? Which infinities??

Comment: @PeterSmith I guess they refer to the infinite set of natural numbers. Would arithmetic on a set of natural numbers with a highest number (ultrafinitism) be complete?

Comment: Goedel himself stated in his (incompleteness) paper that the above procedure is "constructively non-objectionable", however 1) Goedel's reference to contructivism (intuitionism), is rather formal than actual

Comment: 2) negative translation of classical logic to intuitionistic logic **is not intuitionism**, rather a formal analogy, because the semantics of what constitutes a construction, a proof, implication and of course the definition/construction of new entities based on previously constructed entities is totally different (and of course same exists for the incompleteneess proof, where these conditions are neither formalised nor kept)

Comment: 3) intuitionism has, in a sense, embedded the incompletenmess theorems as it accepts statetements which can neither be proved nor refuted (at a given time), and of course Brouwer himself foresaw Goedel's results by a decade at least (and Goedel himself attended Brouwer's lectures on the foundations of mathematics)

Comment: 4) variations of LEM are used throught Godel's paper

Comment: Where exactly does Gödel's paper depend LEM?

Comment: By the way, the first incompleteness proof has been formally proved in Coq, an implementation of the calculus of (co)inductive constructions. This
dependent type theory has intensional equality and is constructive, so the proof can (by normal standards) be indeed regarded as constructive.

Comment: see [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1418923/139391) that elaborates on previous comments

Comment: "_existential quantification for which we can't produce a witness._" How well expressed!

Comment: Is proof by contradiction intuitionistic? It assumes x, reaches some contradiction, and concludes "not x" without constructing a proof for it. Is this not the case?

Comment: But showing that X leads to absurdity is precisely the canonical way of constructing a proof of not-X for an intuitionist! (What is intuitionistically unacceptable is deducing X from a demonstration that not-X leads to contradiction -- intuitionistically that only yields is not-not-X.)

Comment: For me this Answer does not quite answer the question as I would interpret it. The question is not "Is Godel's Theorem proved in an Intuitionistically valid way?", but "Is Godel's Theorem (perhaps modified slightly) valid for Intuitionistic Logic(s)?". The formulation of the Godel Theorem refers to a "consistent Formal System F" - so does F need to be (as often described) a two-valued system like PA? I believe that F does *not* need to be two valued, but that opens up various non-classical options for F, which is what I understand this question to be.

Comment: If we consider an arithmetic with a logic weaker-than-classical, then it can't prove *more* than the corresponding arithmetic with a classical logic: so if the classical version (e.g. of PA) is incomplete so must be the weaker non-classical version.

Comment: Yes, but does not Godel Incompleteness also come with pre-conditions on the theory, so that Incompleteness follows? A sufficiently weak classical theory may not meet those conditions. I am not clear whether all (though I believe some) non-classical arithmetic-based theories meet those conditions. Do not some Intuitionistic theories claim to by-pass Godel in this way?