# Liar sentences and the fixed point theorem

Tags: logic, proof-theory

I apologize in advance for the slightly vague nature of this question.

If one adds a unary predicate $T$ to the language of arithmetic, one gets a sentence $L$ with the property that $L \leftrightarrow \neg T (\ulcorner L \urcorner)$ is a theorem of PA, by the usual fixed point construction.

Suppose however we are in the context of a 3-valued logic in which we may *not* assume that we have $T(x) \vee \neg T(x)$ for all $x$. I'm happy to assume that all the other relations / functions of arithmetic behave in a completely 2-valued way.

Do we still get a sentence $L$ for which $L \leftrightarrow \neg T (\ulcorner L \urcorner)$ is a theorem of PA in this 3-valued logic (however we flesh this out?)

In essence, the question is precisely *how* the Liar paradox is avoided by moving to 3-valued logic. Of course, it may well be the case that 3-valued logic avoids a contradiction in the presence of an $L$ for which the above biconditional is provable in virtue of the failure of excluded middle. That's great. But is it possible that the contradiction is blocked even prior to this in the sense that we don't even get a sentence $L$ for which the biconditional in question is provable in the first place?

Comment: Isn't Gödels proof intuitionistically valid? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448527/are-the-g%C3%B6dels-incompleteness-theorems-valid-for-both-classical-and-intuitionis

Comment: Yes, the proof is intuitionistically valid, but that doesn't quite settle the question. It might be true that the Fixed Point theorem gives us a sentence $G$ for which the biconditional $G \leftrightarrow \neg \text{Provable}_{PA}(\ulcorner G \urcorner)$ is provable, but Provable$_{PA}$ is a predicate for which the law of the excluded middle holds, unlike the predicate $T$ which I am imagining introducing. That the Fixed Point Theorem works in the former sort of case doesn't tell me whether it does in the later.

Comment: What "contradiction" are you talking about?

Comment: Provability does not follow the law of the excluded middle

Comment: Rob Arthan: the usual contradiction that follows from the Liar sentence, Curry sentence, or what have you.

Comment: user2103480: I don't see how that observation helps.

Comment: @user2103480 "Provability does not follow the law of the excluded middle" So an expression of language of some formal system might be neither provable nor not provable?

Comment: It's an unfortunate formulation, what i mean is: an expression and it's negation might be simultaneously unprovable from some set of axioms

Comment: @provocateur okay so this means that if we do not change the valid inference rules for that proof system, then we never use any assumptions on the number of truth values in the proof. If you also change the valid inference rules to those for (some) 3-valued predicate logic, then I'm out of answers

Comment: @polcott And to be fair, provocateur was right that it doesn't address the question, since he was referring to the exact same fact that you mentioned, namely that every sentence is either provable or unprovable from the point of view of the FOL theory. But this is not used if I recall correctly

Comment: @user2103480 "what i mean is: an expression and it's negation might be simultaneously unprovable from some set of axioms"  That makes perfect sense now.

Comment: I would analyze the Liar Paradox like this: ∃LP∃F (LP_F ↔ ¬True(LP_F)), is there an expression of the language of some formal system such that this expression is logically equivalent to its own untruth?